# consulta que visualice el DNI del empleado que ha tenido más trabajos

Tags: mysql

```
create table EMPLEADOS(
DNI VARCHAR(9),
NOMBRE VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
APELLIDO1(150),
SALARIO DECIMAL(10,2),
DIRECC1 VARCHAR(200),
)
contraint fk_empleados primary key (DNI);

create table historial(
DNI_EMPLEADO VARCHAR(9)
TRAB_COD INT,
FECHA_INICIO DATE,
FECHA_FIN DATE
)

CONTRAINT PK_HISTORIAL PRIMARY KEY (DNI_EMPLEADO,FECHA_INICIO),
CONTRAINT FK_EMPLEADO FOREING KEY (DNI_EMPLEADO) REFERENCES EMPLEADOS(DNI);
```

Comment: Agrega por favor lo que hayas intentado

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Una publicación que simplemente dice: "este es mi ejercicio, resuélvanlo", no es bien recibida. Es mejor que incluyas el contexto (usa el botón [edit] para hacer cambios en tu pregunta): incluye que intentaste/investigaste y también cual es el problema puntual que tuviste. Demuestra algo que nos indique que formas parte de la experiencia de aprender a solucionar tu problema.

Answer (score 0):

Para ello lo primero que debes hacer es identificar que campo u variable utilizarás para saber cual es el empleado que tiene mas trabajos.

En este caso podríamos suponer que es el campo; TRAB_COD INT, de la tabla historial.(no está claro)

Pues nada, buscamos en esa tabla cual es el empleado con más trabajo.

SELECT DNI_EMPLEADO, Sum(TRAB_COD) AS Expr1 --> Pedimos el identificador único
FROM historial
GROUP BY TRAB_COD --> lo agrupamos para diferenciar ese campo
ORDER BY Expr1 DESC LIMIT 1; --> escogemos el primero de la lista

ahora que ya tenemos el empleado con más trabajos, abría que realizar una subconsulta con la otra tabla para encontrar el dni de ese trabajador en concreto. Como no especificas y en esta tabla ya existe un campo llamado dni_empleado, lo daré por resuelto y dejaré que indagues por tu cuenta para encontrar la subconsulta o join que necesitarías.